# Estructura JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json

me gustaría saber si alguno de ustedes sabe como lograr esta estructura desde PHP, he intentado con todo pero no logro que suceda

```
{
"0":
[{"Tipo":"2","Titulo":"Una persona está ingresando","Contexto":"Caracteristicas de la persona"}]
,"2": [{"Tipo":"2","Titulo":"Una persona está ingresando","Contexto":"Caracteristicas de la persona"}]
   }
```

Lo necesito tal cual como se presenta pero al generarlo con php no agrega lo siguiente "0":[...]

Comment: ¿Desde dónde quieres generarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera

Indico la estructura del ARRAY iniciandolo con estos valores

```
    $resultsa = array("1" => array(array("Tipo" => "Tipo","Titulo" => "Titulo", "Contexto" => "Contexto")));
```

Luego voy agregando datos al array

```
            $resultsa[] = array(array("Tipo" => $MiConsulta->tipo, "Titulo" => $MiConsulta->titulo, "Contexto" => $MiConsulta->contexto));
```